# getting error in "pretty" in cucumber file

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

Getting below error while running the test runner file,can someone please suggest how to resolve this after changing the different version of the report, still facing the same error

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Only one formatter can use STDOUT, now both pretty and pretty use it. If you use more than one formatter you must specify output path with PLUGIN:PATH_OR_URL
at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.defaultOutOrFailIfAlreadyUsed(PluginFactory.java:185)
at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.convertOrNull(PluginFactory.java:144)
at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.instantiate(PluginFactory.java:99)
at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.create(PluginFactory.java:87)
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.getPlugins(RuntimeOptions.java:245)
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions$1.invoke(RuntimeOptions.java:291)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.done(Unknown Source)
at cucumber.runtime.junit.JUnitReporter.done(JUnitReporter.java:227)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:101)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

***Test Runner File:-***

```
    package com.ntrs.msf.runner;

import java.io.File;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import com.cucumber.listener.Reporter;
import com.ntrs.msf.managers.FileReaderManager;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

//@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@CucumberOptions(tags = {"@IRR515-Test",}, features = "src/test/resources/features/", plugin = { "pretty",
        "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/cucumber-reports/report.html" }, glue = {
                "com/ntrs/msf/stepDefinitions" }, monochrome = false)
public class Holdings515_Test {
    @AfterClass
    public static void writeExtentReport() {
        Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File(FileReaderManager.getInstance().getConfigReader().getReportConfigPath()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of `cucumber-jvm`?

Comment: This is not cucumberjs can you remove that tag

Comment: cucumber-jvm version is 1.0.5...

Comment: You are using a very old version of Cucumber; please try upgrading to a newer version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting exception while executing feature file. I have tried using plugin instead of format, still issue persists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57142113/getting-exception-while-executing-feature-file-i-have-tried-using-plugin-instea)

Answer (score -1):

Try changing `plugin =` to `format =`

Does that help?