# Getting exception while executing feature file. I have tried using plugin instead of format, still issue persists

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

Exception in thread "main" cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Only one formatter can use STDOUT, now both pretty and json use it. If you use more than one formatter you must specify output path with PLUGIN:PATH_OR_URL
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.defaultOutOrFailIfAlreadyUsed(PluginFactory.java:185)
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.convertOrNull(PluginFactory.java:144)
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.instantiate(PluginFactory.java:99)
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.create(PluginFactory.java:87)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.getPlugins(RuntimeOptions.java:241)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions$1.invoke(RuntimeOptions.java:287)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.uri(Unknown Source)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:160)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:121)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:36)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)

Answer (score 1):

Just mention a complete path for the json report in the plugin value of `CucumberOptions`. Something like below

```
plugin = {  "pretty","json:target/json/report.json" }
```

The json report will be generated in the file and pretty plugin will use the console.